# SSH and run commands mid-script

Tags: linux, bash, ssh

I'm writing a bash script to setup a GRE Tunnel, on both local and a remote machine.

How would I be able to (in the middle of the script) be able to have a piece of code that logs into the remote machine, runs the required iptables commands, and logs out, then continues with the setup on the LOCAL machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the client machine is running bash as well, and has the OpenSshClient installed: you can just run `ssh user@host yourCommandToRunWithoutPty`. This runs the command WITHOUT a pty/tty, which is important is some cases, such as `sudo` (`sudo` expects a tty to ask for password).

Because of this, I would suggest adding passwordless access to that command by that user in your server's `/etc/sudoers`, if (securely!) possible.

If configured correctly, your client should be able to just run `ssh user@host sudo iptables --some-iptables-switches`.

**NOTE** When adding passwordless commands to your `/etc/sudoers`, remember to always be as explicit as possible with your arguments, so no one can abuse arguments unintented to be ran without a sudo password.

Comment: Ok, if i wanted to login as root, for example, How would it prompt for the password? I want to ssh login to the remote machine as root, and have the password within the script itself for the machine.

Comment: Login as root is discouraged, as it can pose a security risk. My answer also talks about how it will not launch a pty/tty. That means the session is not interactive, and cannot get input from the user (such as the password input from sudo). I also do not suggest storing the password within the script. I suggest looking into adding passwordless sudo access to certain binaries here https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-edit-the-sudoers-file-on-ubuntu-and-centos

Comment: I'm not so sure about this, What I want to do is, login, and do the iptables commands, Don't I need root for that? How do I prompt the user for their root password? How do I login as root and store the pass within the script? It won't pose security issues for me because I have a unique use for this, and only I will be using it.

Comment: I dont want to use sudo. I want to log in as root, regardless of the security risks, How do I achieve this?

Comment: `nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config` and look for `PermitRootLogin no`, and change it to `PermitRootLogin yes`. Then login with root ad username and the root password.

Comment: How do I implement that into the script? I want to put the user, host, and pass in the script and have it work and login

Comment: You would `PermitRootLogin` on the server. Either install the `sshpass` package to connect to ssh server with a password from command line, or generate a public/private key pair and use those for authentication. This is easily getting out of the scope of the question,  and I suggest looking into some manuals and tutorials regarding ssh for a better and more robust understanding.

Comment: No... I already have rootlogin enabled, I need to know how I can put the password INSIDE the script, and it doesnt need to prompt users for it, password is in the script and it just logs in using root, host, pass (all inside the script)

Comment: Either follow http://www.linuxproblem.org/art_9.html for key pairs (what I suggest for passwordless ssh) OR install the `sshpass` package and simply `sshpass -p your_root_password root@hostname`

Comment: Thanks! And there's no other way? I HAVE to install sshpass? There's no way to do it with currently installed packages? What's the syntax for sshpass? where do I add commands, and can I add multiple commands

Comment: You could generate a private/public key pair on your client and submit the public key to the server's `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file. Then use the private key to connect either using the `-i` switch, or leave the pair in the `~/.ssh/` directory on the client and it will automatically try  to use the key for connections. This is what the tutorial I posted in my previous comment talks about. As for the syntax of `sshpass`, after installing run `man sshpass` to show documentation.

Comment: And no, there is no other way to do what you want; because it is *highly* discouraged to store passwords in scripts. I don't even think the OpenSshClient allows for password logins *without* the session being interactive (as that would result in a *password stored to disk!!!*)

Comment: Is there way to prompt the user for the root/user password instead then?

Comment: Google it and ask another question here if you get stuck.